# Was für einen Unterschied gibt es zwischen den Wörtern "heimlich" und "geheim"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What is the difference between : "heimlich" und "geheim"?

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, both *heimlich* and *geheim* can be used as adjective or adverb, and they translate roughly to *secret(ly)*. Their connotations are, however, different.

*Heimlich* refers to something done covertly, so that noone else can notice that there is a secret. Moreover, there often is furtiveness. Translations more apt than *secret* may be *furtive* or *clandestine*; but there are [various translations](https://www.dict.cc/?s=heimlich) that would fit even better in one situation or the other. Here are two examples:

> Sie trafen sich heimlich in der Nacht.
>   
>   They met furtively at night.
>
> Er hat eine heimliche Liebschaft.
>   
>   He has a clandestine love affair.

*Geheim* does usually not have this furtiveness connotation, and it may well be that other people are aware that a secret exists, although its content is under cover. Again, there are [various translations](https://www.dict.cc/?s=geheim) for different situations. Here are two examples:

> Das ist eine geheime Akte.
>   
>   This is an undercover file.
>
> Bitte halten Sie es geheim!
>   
>   Please, keep it confidential!

Answer (score 3):

They are most times interchangeable.

- **heimlich** is something you **do**, but covertly.
- **geheim** is something which should not be uncovered.

> Lass uns heimlich ins Haus schleichen.

*Let us sneak into the house covertly.*

> Halte bitte den Termin noch geheim.

*Please keep the date a secret for now.*

Answer (score -1):

Heimlich stands for : **secretly**

> heimlich küssen
>
> kiss secretly

Geheim stands for :  **secret**

> Ich halte meine Methoden geheim
>
> I keep my methods, secret

Comment: The question is about *geheim*, not *Geheimnis*. Could you change your 2nd example accordingly?

Comment: This answer is not correct! _Geheim_ is an adjective meaning _secret_ or, if used as an adverb, _secretly_. It is not **a secret**. That would rather be the noun _Geheimnis_. The same is true for _heimlich_, which is often used as an adverb, but which may well be used as an adjective, such as in _eine heimliche Beziehung_ (a secret relationship). Aside from that, there are often more appropriate translations than _secret_.